# Count how many times a line passes near, through, etc

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I am carrying out a work where I have to know how many times a cable (line) passes through a pole (point), I have this information in QGIS:

[image: information I have in QGIS]

As can be seen in the image, the layer of lines has two colors, since they are two different types of cables, and each point would represent a cable.

How can I identify each time a line passes near, crosses the line

Each point has a number, so knowing how many times the cable passes through each point is of great interest.

I have basic knowledge in QGIS

Comment: this feels like a bit of SQL request and geometric function (St_crosses, St_intersects) + a group by point id and your data as geopackage can do the trick. You can do some research with this keywords, i'll try to produce an exemple later ... You can also add a sample off your data to show how it is organised

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Having an "and" in the title, and in the Question with a question mark makes this two questions. If you can capture this information, then exporting it to Excel is probably already answered here.

Comment: I have edited my question to avoid breaking the rules.

Comment: How about a [spatial join](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)?